# What's the difference between these two SQL queries?

Tags: sql

SELECT title, release_year, language
FROM films
WHERE release_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2000
AND budget > 100000000
**AND language = 'Spanish' OR language = 'French'**

SELECT title, release_year, language
FROM films
WHERE release_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2000
AND budget > 100000000
**AND language = ('Spanish'OR language = 'French')**

Why does the first query is receiving data for the years such as 1964, 1965? Because my BETWEEN command specifically asks for data in the range 1990 and 2000.

Can someone please help?

Comment: The first query is ambiguous, the second is a syntax error.  Probably should be `AND (language = 'Spanish' OR language = 'French')`

Comment: In your first statement, You have, using the OR, stated that it is enough that the language is french OR if it is Spanish you have some more criteria that are important. If you are unsure how these works try using the In clause. AND language in ('Spanish','French')

Answer (score 1):

Mind your parentheses. Query should be

```
SELECT title, release_year, language FROM films WHERE release_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2000
AND budget > 100000000 AND (language = 'Spanish' OR language = 'French')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the logical processing of `and` and `or`.

Consider `where a=1 and b=2 or b=3`

Does this mean **a** must be 1 *and* **b** must be 2 or 3, OR does it mean **a** must be 1 and **b** must be 2, OR **b** can be 3 with any value for **a**

Use parenthesis to be explicit:

`where a = 1 and (b = 2 or b = 3)`

If you properly separate the conditions on each line it makes it much easier to see the intention at a glance.

```
SELECT title, release_year, language 
FROM films 
WHERE release_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2000
  AND budget > 100000000 
  AND (language = 'Spanish' OR language = 'French');
```

You can eliminate the use of OR here by simply using `in`

```
SELECT title, release_year, language 
FROM films 
WHERE release_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2000
  AND budget > 100000000 
  AND language IN ('Spanish', 'French');
```